# Predict for multiple rows for single/multiple timesteps lstm

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, keras, lstm, forecasting

I have data with 250 days, 72 features of training sample and one column of target variable. And want to predict for next 30 days for each of 21351 rows with 72 features. How will I reshape my data both input and output. It seems that I am having a little confusion and the library is giving me error about shape incompatiblity.

I was reshaping as:

```
trainX.reshape(1, len(trainX), trainX.shape[1])

trainY.reshape(1, len(trainX))
```

But gives me error:

> ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as
>   target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 250 target samples.

Same error with:

```
trainX.reshape(1, len(trainX), trainX.shape[1])

trainY.reshape(len(trainX), )
```

and same error with:

```
trainX.reshape(1, len(trainX), trainX.shape[1])

trainY.reshape(len(trainX), 1)
```

Currently, trainX is reshaped as:

```
trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1])

array([[[  4.49027601e+00,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01, ...,
           1.06175239e+17,   1.24734085e+06,   5.16668131e+00]],

       [[  2.05921386e+00,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01, ...,
           8.44426594e+17,   1.39098642e+06,   4.01803817e+00]],

       [[  9.25515792e+00,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01, ...,
           4.08800518e+17,   1.24441013e+06,   3.69129399e+00]],

       ..., 
       [[  3.80037999e+00,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01, ...,
           1.35414902e+18,   1.23823291e+06,   3.54601899e+00]],

       [[  3.73994822e+00,  -3.71848297e-01,   8.40698741e+00, ...,
           3.93863169e+17,   1.25693299e+06,   3.29993440e+00]],

       [[  3.56843035e+00,  -3.71848297e-01,   1.53710656e+00, ...,
           3.28306336e+17,   1.22667253e+06,   3.36569960e+00]]])
```

trainY reshaped as:

```
trainY.reshape(trainY.shape[0], )

array([[-0.7238661 ],

       [-0.43128777],

       [-0.31542821],

       [-0.35185375],

       ...,

       [-0.28319519],

       [-0.28740503],

       [-0.24209411],

       [-0.3202021 ]])
```

and testX reshaped as:

```
testX.reshape(1, testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1])

array([[[ -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01, ...,
          -3.71848297e-01,   2.73982042e+06,  -3.71848297e-01],

        [ -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01, ...,
          -3.71848297e-01,   2.73982042e+06,  -3.71848297e-01],

        [ -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01, ...,
           2.00988794e+18,   1.05992636e+06,   2.49920150e+01],

       ..., 

        [ -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01, ...,
          -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01],

        [ -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01, ...,
          -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01],

        [ -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01, ...,
          -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01,  -3.71848297e-01]]])
```

and error is:

> ValueError: Error when checking : expected lstm_25_input to have shape
>   (None, 1, 72) but got array with shape (1, 2895067, 72)

**EDIT 1:**

Here is code of my model:

```
trainX = trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1])
trainY = trainY.reshape(trainY.shape[0], )
testX = testX.reshape(1, testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1])

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, input_shape = trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=500, shuffle=False, verbose=1)

model.save('model_lstm.h5')

model = load_model('model_lstm.h5')

prediction = model.predict(testX, verbose=0)
```

> ---
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        43     model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
>        44 
>   ---> 45     model.fit(exog, endog, epochs=50, shuffle=False, verbose=1)
>        46 
>        47     start_date = endog_end + timedelta(days = 1)
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in fit(self, x, y,
>   batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split,
>   validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch,
>   **kwargs)
>       865                               class_weight=class_weight,
>       866                               sample_weight=sample_weight,
>   --> 867                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
>       868 
>       869     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self,
>   x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split,
>   validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch,
>   steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)    1520
>   class_weight=class_weight,    1521             check_batch_axis=False,
>   -> 1522             batch_size=batch_size)    1523         # Prepare validation data.    1524         do_validation = False
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in
>   _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_batch_axis, batch_size)    1376
>   self._feed_input_shapes,    1377
>   check_batch_axis=False,
>   -> 1378                                     exception_prefix='input')    1379         y = _standardize_input_data(y, self._feed_output_names,
>   1380                                     output_shapes,
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in
>   _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
>       142                             ' to have shape ' + str(shapes[i]) +
>       143                             ' but got array with shape ' +
>   --> 144                             str(array.shape))
>       145     return arrays
>       146
>
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_31_input to have
>   shape (None, 250, 72) but got array with shape (21351, 1, 72)

**EDIT 2:**

After trying the updated solution from @Paddy, I got this error on calling predict():

> ---
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 model = load_model('model_lstm.h5')
>         2 
>   ----> 3 prediction = model.predict(exog_test, verbose=0)
>         4 #     for x in range(0, len(exog_test)):
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in predict(self, x,
>   batch_size, verbose)
>       911         if not self.built:
>       912             self.build()
>   --> 913         return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
>       914 
>       915     def predict_on_batch(self, x):
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in
>   predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)    1693         x =
>   _standardize_input_data(x, self._feed_input_names,    1694                                     self._feed_input_shapes,
>   -> 1695                                     check_batch_axis=False)    1696         if self.stateful:    1697             if x[0].shape[0] >
>   batch_size and x[0].shape[0] % batch_size != 0:
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in
>   _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
>       130                                  ' to have ' + str(len(shapes[i])) +
>       131                                  ' dimensions, but got array with shape ' +
>   --> 132                                  str(array.shape))
>       133             for j, (dim, ref_dim) in enumerate(zip(array.shape, shapes[i])):
>       134                 if not j and not check_batch_axis:
>
> ValueError: Error when checking : expected lstm_64_input to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (2895067, 72)

Comment: I have successfully trained the model. But it gives me error on calling predict().

Comment: you passed the wrong dimensions to testX

Comment: @djk47463 So can you provide me the line of reshaping the testX? That's what I am struggling with.

Comment: The main concern is to get the desired output according to requirement.

Comment: @djk47463 in the chat discussion you suggested a single step of concatenating and reshaping the array. But it is not working for me on my original dataset. I have 274 rows and 72 features and want to make timesteps of length 92. but it gives me error about size incompatibility. Please help me.

Comment: @djk47463 like so, 

exog2_sep16 = np.concatenate([exog_sep16[x : x + 92,:].reshape(1, 92, exog_sep16.shape[1]) for x in range(exog_sep16.shape[0]-1)]) 

and error is: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6552 into shape (1,92,72)

Comment: Well I need to put 91 in loop like so,  exog2_sep16 = np.concatenate([exog_sep16[x : x + 92,:].reshape(1, 92, exog_sep16.shape[1]) for x in range(exog_sep16.shape[0]-91)]). This resolved the issue. Please review if I did it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
trainX = trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1])
trainY = trainY.reshape(trainY.shape[0], )
testX = testX.reshape(1, testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1])
```

You want:

```
trainX = trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1])
trainY = trainY.reshape(trainY.shape[0], )
testX = testX.reshape(testX.shape[0],1, testX.shape[1])
```

You mixed up the samples and time-step dimensions in testX

Comment: Yeah, I had tried it and it solved my issue. I was just getting the dims of testX wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this reshape:

```
trainX.reshape(len(trainX),1, trainX.shape[1])

trainY.reshape(len(trainX), 1)
```

But, in general you have two ways, either reshape input data or change the model parameters.

And please please look on the error message, it says everything here!

ok, here is an update for your code:

```
trainX = trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1],1)
trainY = trainY.reshape(trainY.shape[0],)
testX = testX.reshape(testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1], 1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences= True, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1],1) ))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences= False))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=500, shuffle=False, verbose=1)

model.save('model_lstm.h5')

model = load_model('model_lstm.h5')

prediction = model.predict(testX, verbose=0)
```

Comment: Yeah, I have reshaped it like you said, as well. Please look at the last three reshaping code snippets for trainX, trainY, testX respectively. Then it becomes incompatible with shape of testX (as stated in error message). Please note that I want predict mulitple steps (30 days, say) for each record in testX.

Comment: Also Why have you moved 1 to the last argument in reshape()? It seperates each feature into it's own array.

Comment: please check my answer once again :)

Comment: about the 1, normally the smallest number is going to the right, you can check how to prepare shapes for LSTM is you want to know more...

Comment: No, I don't think so. Because it will break columns of each row into rows of single element. Wesley's answer has solved the issue. Thanks again for your time :)

Comment: the model calculates mean_squared_error. what change do we have in model.compile to computer multiple losses (like mse, mae, rmse)?